# Why is NSCachesDirectory read only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

is it possible that the `NSCachesDirectory` becomes read only on the device ? Some users of my app were reporting some bugs and I pinned point it to this

```
NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"VideoCache"];

NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error while trying to create directory at path %@: %@", path, error.description);
    path = nil;
}

NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"config.json"];

NSDictionary * json = @{ @"foo" : @"bar"};
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:json options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

[jsonData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

The `writeToFile` crashes because `path` is nil. In which situations do the `createDirectoryAtPath` can return an error when creating a dir in the caches folder ? The only way I managed to reproduce it on Simulator is by setting the app's cache folder to read only.

thanks

Comment: What does the error message say?  Without knowing that it's anyone's guess.  Sounds like you need a better error-reporting mechanism.  For example you could use Crashlytics and log the error message with them and throw an exception as that is a fatal error.  You will then be able to view the error messages in the Crashlytics console online within minutes of the crash.

Comment: Also note that you should be checking the return value from `createDirectoryAtPath` and not `error != nil`.